# iphone building a view in a separate thread

Tags: iphone, multithreading, view

I have a large modal view that pops up and it requires lots of other little views to be build, rendered and then added. I have been doing this asyncronisely by building the view parts aync and only performmingselectoronMainthread when necessary.

This is all good unless the user wants to quit out of the view (using a close button) before its finished rendering. How would I safely stop the view from rendering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You generally do *not* want to kill threads. Probably the cleanest way to handle this would be to turn your view into a "zombie" that accepts the input from the secondary threads, but does nothing with it. If at all possible, you also want to have your secondary threads accept a signal telling them to quit as soon as possible (or at least as soon as reasonable, anyway).

Comment: The other issue is memory cleanup. I can't dealloc the view is completely gone otherwise the building thread comes back and the view is a memory zombie.